# What are metal pans and covers of a staircase?

Tags: meaning, nouns, meaning-in-context

What are metal pans and its covers of a staircase and what do they look like as mentioned in the following account?

> My boss and I were carrying 160lb sliding glass doors up an unfinished staircase (just metal pans with no covers so you were walking on a surface about 3/4" wide, with water in the bottom because it had been raining.)

Comment: imagine if you took the treads (flat surface that you normally walk on) off of a stairway.  That would leave just a series of rectangular boxes open at the top- Kind of like a bunch of loaf pans angling up. So they could only step on the edges of the loaf pans which were about 3/4" thick.

Comment: This might be a good question for [diy.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image below [from [weldingweb.com](http://weldingweb.com/showthread.php?t=24965)] illustrates one type of stair pan.  The narrow raised forward edge probably is the  “3/4" wide” rail referred to in the quote, and is what would cause the pan to retain water.

[image: staircase with pans]

This staircase would be finished by placing wood or concrete steps (or covers) onto or into each pan.

Comment: So he is not actually walking on a 3/4" surface like he said since the pans are not open/hollowed out, he is still being supported on the main surface? Maybe the pans he's talking about has taller raised edges? – Theo 8 mins ago

Comment: By  “walking on a 3/4" surface” the writer might mean that stepping on the raised front lip could not be avoided.  On typical residential stairs, if the toe of my boot is against the riser, the heel is out over the edge of the tread.

Comment: By "walking on a 3/4" surface", I assume the writer is saying that he was trying to step only on the raised edges and not in the pans, which would have gotten his shoes very wet. This isn't what he literally said, but I think it likely is what he meant.